# How do I have 1 UI thread wait for another UI thread

Tags: java, user-interface, multithreading

I have two UI threads.
I want to make sure the first one is finishing running, and then run the other one.
How could I do that?
Thanks a lot!

```
UIJob uiJob = new UIJob("settext1") {
    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor ipm) {
        webBrowser.setText(finalContent);
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};
uiJob.schedule();

UIJob uiJob2 = new UIJob("settext2") {
    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor ipm) {
        webBrowser.execute(executeMoreFunction);
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }
};
uiJob2.schedule();
```

Comment: I assume you mean in Basic, maybe Fortran? Or did you mean another language? That's kind of an important detail :)

Comment: Which language/GUI toolkit lets you have more than one UI thread?

Comment: Hi, 
It is java .
       UIJob uiJob = new UIJob("settext1") {
        
        public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor ipm) {

         webBrowser.setText(finalContent);
         
         return Status.OK_STATUS;
        }

       };
       uiJob.schedule();


   UIJob uiJob2 = new UIJob("settext2") {
    
    public IStatus runInUIThread(IProgressMonitor ipm) {

     webBrowser.execute(executeMoreFunction);
     
     return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }

   };
   uiJob2.schedule();

Comment: You can click edit on your question to add this, highlight the test and click the 1010 on the bar up top to quickly format code for highlighting as well :)

Comment: Hi,

I don't see 1010 on the bar up top...

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Call the `join` method after `schedule`.

> Waits until this job is finished. This method will block the calling thread until the
>   job has finished executing, or until this thread has been interrupted. If the job
>   has not been scheduled, this method returns immediately. A job must not
>   be joined from within the scope of its run method.
>   If this method is called on a job that reschedules itself from within the
>   run method, the join will return at the end of the first execution.
>   In other words, join will return the first time this job exits the
>   RUNNING state, or as soon as this job enters the NONE state.
>   If this method is called while the job manager is suspended, this job
>   will only be joined if it is already running; if this job is waiting or sleeping,
>   this method returns immediately.
>   **Note that there is a deadlock risk when using join. If the calling thread owns
>   a lock or object monitor that the joined thread is waiting for, deadlock
>   will occur.**

Read more: http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/core/runtime/jobs/Job.java.htm#ixzz0qWh6Ahhe

Comment: Can I use this then?

    private ISchedulingRule schedulingRule = new ISchedulingRule() {
  public boolean contains(ISchedulingRule rule) {
   return (rule == this);
  }
  public boolean isConflicting(ISchedulingRule rule) {
   return (rule == this);
  }
    };

Then set the rule to the each job before scheduling:
  job1.setRule(schedulingRule); 
  job1.schedule();
  job2.setRule(schedulingRule);
  job2.schedule();

Answer (score 1):

From [eclipse sdk help](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/progress/UIJob.html):

> The UIJob is a Job that runs within the UI Thread via an asyncExec.

It is only one UI thread, two `UIJob`:s cannot wait for eachother, it will create a deadlock.